# Concatenation of two cURL commands fails, but the commands work separately

Tags: command-line, authentication, curl, pipe

I am trying to concatenate two `curl` commands using a pipe.

First there is a simple authentication that works using

```
curl https://myserver --user username:password
```

Second I need to use GLPI API for that I have to do an initSession. the code is below:

```
curl -X GET \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H "Authorization: user_token mytoken1" \
-H "App-Token: mytoken2" \ 
'https://domaine/apirest.php/initSession'
```

But the concatenation seems not to work:

```
curl https://domaine.com --user username:password | curl -X GET \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H "Authorization: user_token mytoken1" \
-H "App-Token: mytoken2" \ 
'https://domaine/apirest.php/initSession'
```

What's the problem and how might I fix it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what you want to do by piping one `curl` process to another. A [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) sends [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdout) of one process to [stdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdin) of another. In your case, it means two independent HTTPS connections. Moreover, `curl` does not accept stdin unless an appropriate parameter is used, see [`man curl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) (search for `stdin`).

Answer (score -1):

This is only possible if you use for example a php script and use [curl_multi_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to demonstrate how it solves the problem. I am afraid it’s not the solution here.